# django filter queryset based on list of dates and get the count on each day

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

I have a model like this

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
  date = models.DatetimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

and i have a list of dates (dates of last seven days, it can be dates of last 30 days as well). What i am trying to do is get the number of MyModel objects created in a particular day in all of the dates. Like below.

```
[{'date1': 2}, {'date2': 3}, {'date3': 7}....{'daten':26}]
```

the keys of the dictoary are dates and values are the number of objects created in that particular date. by using a forloop and hitting db multiple times i am getting the output, but is there a way to get it from a single query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a query that counts the number of objects for each date:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.db.models import Count, F
from django.utils.timezone import now

qs = MyModel.objects.filter(
    date__date__gte=now().date()-timedelta(days=30)
).values(
    datedate=F('date__date')
).annotate(
    number=Count('pk')
).order_by('datedate')
```

Next we can post-process this to a list of dictionaries, or perhaps better a single dictionary that maps the data on the count:

```
# list of dictionaries
[{r['datedate']: r['number']} for r in qs]

# single dictionary
{r['datedate']: r['number'] for r in qs}
```

If the date is not present, it will not be in the dictionary. So dates that are not in the dictionary have count `0`. This is due to the *closed world assumption (CWA)*.

Comment: awesome! this worked like a charm. Is there any way to fill object count 0 entries also to the dict ?

Comment: @SandeepBalagopal: you should iterate over `date` objects in the range, and manually add extra values. So post-edit the dictionary/list. Except for that no.

Comment: I ran into an issue on this. seems the group by is not working. this is what i am getting <MyModelQuerySet [{'datedate': datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 8, 5, 48, 23), 'number': 1}, {'datedate': datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 8, 5, 53, 21), 'number': 1}]>

Comment: @SandeepBalagopal: well you use `datetime` so including the *time* part. The odds that the timestamp is exactly the same is not very great. That is why we use `F('date__date')` so with the `__date` lookup to convert it to a `date` object.

Comment: i just got it working by qs = MyModel.objects.filter(
    date__date__gte=now().date()-timedelta(days=30)
).values(
    'date__date'
).annotate(
    number=Count('pk')
).order_by('date__date')